# How can I view cascades in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to cascades, I just did something like this,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_deck_link_2`(
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
`deck_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (deck_id) REFERENCES test_deck (id)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
ENGINE=InnoDB 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO decks (user_id,header)VALUES(1,"foo");

ALTER TABLE deck_ratings
   ADD CONSTRAINT `deck_rating_contraint`
   FOREIGN KEY (`deck_id` )
   REFERENCES `decks` (`deck_id` )
   ON DELETE CASCADE
```

How can I view these inside of my database? As of now I can only see the structure of the rows, but not the foreign keys or cascades on them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try to execute this query:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
```

or you can use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `yourtablename`
```

which will give you the definition of the table along with the foreign key constraints.